# Splunk usage for UI events and activity

Tags: splunk

One of the main functions we are attempting to fill is to log/visualise application UI events from users.

We currently log events on our iPhone application to a custom built 'backend' where we can see for each user what they have done, ie start_activity, add_option, take_photo etc etc pretty much as they do it. We are needing the same for the google appengine application that we are building, for both client side and server side events.

I am wondering if splunk would be useable for this, or should we be using another tool first (like with nagios for infrastructure stuff then forwarding on)? Otherwise should we just use a Mixpanel or other app for events logging? Or can we just pump straight into splunk and build off that?

Answer (score 0):

With Splunk you can easily count the number of occurrences of "events" (literal data) in log data that happen over various periods of time.  For example, if you want to count the number of times a photo has been taken you would perform the following SEARCH command in Splunk:

```
'take_photo' | timechart span=1h count
```

This will count the number of log records containing "take_photo" in each hour charting the results.